# How to rename columns in multiple csv files in a folder?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv files in a folder

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jyu2rj2ra01vuvb/AADht6uAhJcjnSjIFpNufVlka?dl=0

How to rename the columns of all the files in the folder as the following

```
S.No    Fruit   Vendor  Price
```

Input:

Expected Output:

File df1

```
S.No    Fruit   VendorA PriceA
1       Apple     AB    89
2       Banana    CA    72
```

File df2

```
S.No    Fruit   VendorB PriceB
1       Mango       AB  55
2       Watermelon  BC  23
```

Expected Output:

File df1

```
S.No    Fruit   Vendor  Price
1       Apple     AB    89
2       Banana    CA    72
```

File df2

```
S.No    Fruit   Vendor  Price
1       Mango       AB  55
2       Watermelon  BC  23
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample rather than expecting people to go off-site

Comment: Please show your attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: @Mad Physicist I know how to rename columns but I don't know how to make it for multiple files. df1.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'}, inplace=True)

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in `pandas` dataframes:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
```

#### Assign a column list with the names that you want

```
col_list = ['S.No','Fruit','Vendor','Price']
```

#### Assign this col list to the dataframe

```
df.columns = col_list
```

#### Write this dataframe into another csv

```
df.to_csv('new_df1.csv', index=False)
```

Do this for all dataframes. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: this is for a single csv I want it for all the files in folder

Comment: Then just create a function using above steps.

Comment: Ok will do that

Answer (score 0):

If you don't stricly required to use pandas. There are other solution that will perform way better than panda.

```
import shutil
import glob

files = glob.glob(".\*.csv")

for i in range(len(files)):
    from_file = open(files[i]) 

    to_file = open(files[i], mode="w")
    to_file.write("S.No,Fruit,Vendor,Price\n")
    shutil.copyfileobj(from_file, to_file)
```

This way you can get all the files in the folder with `.csv` extention. Also you don't even read a single line. So that this will work way faster if you csv file gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use this:

```
files = ['df1.csv', 'df2.csv']
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    data[0] = 'S.no,Fruit,Vendor,Price'+'\n'
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for element in data:
            f.write(element)
```